# Plotly Dash app.long_callback reloading the app

Tags: callback, plotly-dash

When triggering a long callback, the Python libraries associated to the ongoing Dash app get re-loaded. This happens each time the trigger of the long callback happens. How to avoid it? Some libraries take time to be imported, and the re-load slows down my app.

The problem persists even though the debug mode, and the `dev_tools_hot_reload` and `use_reloader` parameters are set to False.